# Find polarity (Objectivity and Subjectivity) of a whole sentence in python?

Tags: nlp, nltk

I am working on python and want to find the polarity of a whole sentence using `NKTL` library. For example: `I watched an awesome play.` `(Positive)` `I saw a nightmare` `Negative`.  Is it possible in python?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but your question is far too broad for this site. Please try to get accustomed with NLTK and Python first and come back here when you have a more specific question.

Comment: @lenz "Yes it is possible" then kindly tell us How can we do that?

Comment: What you are asking about is taught in a course of one or two terms, but cannot be answered in a SO answer post. Please have a look at [what is considered on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on SO.

Comment: Check the publications and resources in the Sentiment Analysis sharedtasks of 2016 and previous years. Example: http://alt.qcri.org/semeval2016/task4/